# why does this evaluate to true

Tags: php

Whey does this evaluate to true?

```
<?php


$val2=0;

//outputs that is an error123
if($val2=='error123'){
   echo 'that is an error123<br />';
}else{
   echo 'that is not an error123<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're comparing a string to an integer. To make the comparison the string is first converted to an integer. When `'error123'` is converted to an integer it becomes 0.

```
echo intval("error123");
```

Result:

```
0
```

In the PHP manual there is [an explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for this behaviour.

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number  and the comparison performed numerically.

There is a quick reference page [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) that shows you the result of various comparions. See the table "Loose comparisons with ==". The interesting part with regard to this question is that `0 == "php"` is shown as TRUE.

There is also a page on [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). A [user comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#89916) on that page gives nearly the exact same example as this.

If you don't want the type juggling use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: So if he were to go the other way around, `'error123'==$val2`, would this evaluate to false?

Comment: @wallacoloo No, it would also evaluate as true. The operator == forces a numerical evaluation, if one of the operands is a number... and  also if the strings are "numeric". It's insane, indeed. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: i guess makes sense; don't use ===. or int's are dominant

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try: `$val2==='error123'`

That will evaluate the value *and* the type of the variable. More here:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php