# Why does var_export( 0 == 'xxx') return true?

Tags: php

In php if you do `var_export( 0 == 'xxx' )` it returns true. How does that logically make sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901029/why-does-this-evaluate-to-true?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that PHP will type-cast values for you. Since you're doing an integer-to-string comparison, the `xxx` will be converted to an int, and since there's no valid number-y type values in there, `xxx` will become `0`. so you're effectively testing `0 == 0`, which is always true.

If you had something like `0 == '42xx'`, then it'd convert to `0 == 42` and be false.

There's also the strict equality tests, `===`, which compare value AND type, where, `0 === 'xxx'` is `FALSE`.